# How do I connect my Blazor project to SignalR via Azure Functions

Tags: azure-functions, signalr, blazor-webassembly

Disclosure: I'm learning C#/.net while developing this.

I am looking to create a Blazor FrontEnd to access data from an already existing stack that includes azure functions, and signalR amongst other things. The existing stack connects to the signalR via sending a request to an azurefunctions negotiate function that returns the singalR connection URL and an access token. I am struggling to create the same request with Blazor.
When I try something like

```
signalRConnectionInfo = await Http.GetFromJsonAsync<SignalRConnectionInfo>("hostedAzureFunctionURI/negotiate");
```

the request is prepending the blazor project URI
[image]

What am I misunderstanding on how to make external calls from Blazor?

working TS request code to get Azure Functions conneceted:

```
private getConnectionInfo(value: string): Observable<SignalRConnectionInfo> {
const requestUrl = `${this.ApiBaseUrl}/negotiate`;
return this.httpClient.get<SignalRConnectionInfo>(requestUrl, this.GetHttpHeader(value));
 }
private GetHttpHeader(value: string) {
    return {
      headers: new HttpHeaders(
        { 'x-ms-client-principal-id': value },
      )
    };
  }
```